# html5 video-tag: is it possible to limit size of the fullscreen-video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm using a `<video`> tag to display a video (800 x 450) inside a webpage, often scaled down due to responsive design. When looking at it at a 4K-TV and switching it to fullscreen-mode, the video gets grisly artefacts, because it's scaled up too much. But I need the full-screen-mode on other screen-resolutions. So the idea was to limit the fullscreen-mode as well to 800 x 450 (or perhaps 1600 x 900).

Is this possible with the embedded `<video`> tag? Or is there any (free?) javascript-player which is able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) it seems that is not possible to control how the browser/videos are being displayed in FullScreen mode.

Moreover, you can only request to open your video in fullscreen and not "demand it". The browser will decide if it will open or not by asking permission to the user.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that ;)